# Fadein with some frame in a web page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a web site where i have three frame. A frame in top, a frame for the menu and a frame for the elements of my web site.
In the JSP of my menu i have some buttons. A button of my menu opens a div popup. This is the code in jquery:

```
$(".open").click(
    function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#box').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

The "box" is a div that contain an iframe and it is defined in the jsp of menu. If I click on my button, the "box" is opened in the menu frame, but i would that the "box" opened in full screen in my page over all three frame. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked @ http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/ ?

you're reinventing the wheel here, this jquery plugin very easy to set up and very popular so plenty of help out there with it.

```
// select one or more elements to be overlay triggers
$(".my_overlay_trigger").overlay({

// one configuration property
 color: '#ccc',

  // another property
  top: 50

  // ... the rest of the configuration properties
});
```

its as easy as that to make exactly what your looking for.. http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html (modal with the mask over whole page)

```
 var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
   // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
  mask: {
    color: '#ebecff',
    loadSpeed: 200,
    opacity: 0.9
  },

  closeOnClick: false
 });
```